# What's different between server oriented WebAPI and mobile app oriented WebAPI?

Tags: rest, session, authentication, cookies

RESTFul Web API usually is designed for server oriented services, in most cases, the client will request an access token with its apiKey/apiSecret.

In mobile app oriented WebAPI, especially consumer oriented applications, the end users don't care apiKey/apiSecret, they just know their username/password.

Should I say the mobile app is actually some kind of browser, it will transfer username/password to get cookie, and access the Web API with cookie to get back JSON object from the server. And the server can use cookie/session to track the user operation via Web API?

So their authentication method (token and cookie/session) are the major difference ?

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. The RESTful API is designed to be client agnostic with hight network reliability (firewalls, routers and other intermediaries will often allow HTTP(S) traffic through even when preventing other connections). Also, your description for the mobile app oriented WebAPI seems inaccurate. It's more likely the required credentials are related to authentication requirements (user data access vs. global data access) than design differences.

Comment: Do you mean I can reuse existing RESTFul API in server, and the mobile app can access the RESTFul API with apikey/secret/token issued by the server? When user operates the APP, it access the resources under the user (by username/password combination) ? Is there any paper/tutorial/blog I can read on for detail? Thanks in advance.